# Passing state/data down functional components, am i doing it wrong/easier way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**DISCLAIMER**I'm relatively new to coding so sorry if this is a simple answer!

**My problem:**

I'm trying to render a modal which sends contact information to my PostgreSQL database with a onclick.

The modal should pick out a `role_id` from the block its associated too however when i pass it down the tree its console logging as undefined.

Any idea where I'm going wrong, have sent ages trying to figure it out but need some constructive help!!!

**This is the parent component:**
*please note, `ListedContracts` is imported elsewhere but working as required.

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ApplyModal from './ApplyModal'

const ListContracts = () => {
  const [contracts, setContracts] = useState([]);

  //lists the contract

  const getContracts = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/freelancedashboard/contracts");
      const jsonData = await res.json();

      setContracts(jsonData);

    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    getContracts();
  }, []);


const renderTable = () => {

  return contracts.map((contract) => {
    const { user_id, role_id, title, industry, skills, discription } = contract //destructuring
    return (
       <tr key={role_id}>
          <td>{user_id}</td>
          <td>{title}</td>
          <td>{industry}</td>
          <td>{skills}</td>
          <td>{discription}</td>
          <td>{role_id}</td>
          <td>
            <ApplyModal role_id = {role_id} />
          </td>
       </tr>
    )
 })

};
  return (
    <Fragment>
    <table class="table mt-5 text-center" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Job Role</th>
        <th>Idustry</th>
        <th>Skills Required</th>
        <th>Brief</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {renderTable()}
    </tbody>
  </table>

    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ListContracts;
```

Which then I'm using the imported child component `ApplyModal` in the render statement of parent`ListContracts` and passing down `role_id` in as a data property...

**ApplyModal looks like:**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Apply from "./Apply";



function ApplyModal(role_id) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  
  
    return (
      <>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
          Apply
        </Button>
  
        <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
             <Modal.Title>Send Your Info</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
              <Apply role_id = {role_id} />
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
             <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Close
             </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </>
      
    );

    
  }

  export default ApplyModal;
```

Which is originally taking in the `role_id` from `ListContract` and then passing it too `Apply` as `role_id`'s final destination.

**Apply**

```
import React, {useState, Fragment, useEffect} from "react";

const Apply = (role_id) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
  });  

  const { name, email } = state;

  

//DISPLAY DATA
 const applyMinor = async () => { 

    try {

      //recieves data from server
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/freelancedashboard/freelanceprofile", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { token: localStorage.token }
      });

      const parseData = await res.json();

      const name = await parseData.user_name;
      const email = await parseData.user_email;


      setState({name: name, email: email})

      
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);   
    }
 } 


 //SENDS DATA

const [role, setRole] = useState({role: ''})

const sendData = async role_id => {

  setRole({role: role_id})

try {

    const body = { role, name, email };
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/application/${role}`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          token: localStorage.token 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      }
    );

    console.log(role, name);
  
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);   
}
  
}


 useEffect(() => {
  applyMinor();
  }, []);



  return (
      <Fragment>
        <div>
          <div>
            <h1>Name: {name}</h1>
            <h1>Email: {email}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => sendData()}>Send</button>
          </div>
          <div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
  )

};


export default Apply;
```

However as previously mentioned, when i console log it as in `Apply` above the content doesn't `console.log(role);`.

What am i doing wrong, I know I'm new and naive but any help would go a long way (towards my learning)?

Thanks team!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of a functional component is a single object that contains all of the props that are passed with the component.

So in your `ApplyModal` and `Apply` components what you're actually accessing when you try to read `role_id` is the entire props object. Try deserialising it like this:

```
function ApplyModal({ role_id }) {
...
}

const Apply = ({ role_id }) => {
...
}
```

As a sidenote - React doesn't use html, it uses something extremely similar called jsx. It's almost identical but there are a few differences like `className` replaces `class`. So you need to change where it says `<table class="table mt-5 text-center" >` to `<table className="table mt-5 text-center" >`